# Foreach hel! `SELECT` getting confused

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Tired and getting dense. I am trying to nest `foreach` statements around two simple DB enquiries.

```
<?php

try {
    $sql ="SELECT id FROM transmission WHERE person_id = 1;";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    echo "stop <br>";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $output = 'Error getting messages ready  etc';
} //END CATCH 

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $id_transmission = $row['id'];  

    try {
        echo "Start <br>";
        $sql ='SELECT day FROM day_schedule WHERE :val ORDER BY FIELD(day, "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");';

        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':val',$id_transmission);
        $result2=$s->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $output = 'Error getting etc';
    }

    foreach ($result2 as $row){
        $id_day = $row['day'];  
        echo "<br><BR>Day id is  $id_day ";
    } //END FOR EACH
} //END FOR EACH
?>
```

I am just trying to get the values from the first select (1,4 and 9) and use them in the second select (the first select will use prepare BTW).

I always suffer from brain freeze with arrays. Can someone please hit me around the head with a cold fish. Thanks

**EDIT: SOLUTION** If I simply replace `$result2=$s->execute();` by `$s->execute();` `$result2=$s;` works exactly as I want. See below for more. Thanks all.

Comment: any reason for using `echo "Start<br>";` at the beginning of the 2nd `try`...?

Comment: Why don't you store the ids **or** use a one-shot query with a `IN` you would probably be less confused (NB: you second query where close is strange)

Comment: I think you have issue in your query you dont have specified column name in where condition.

Comment: You should explain how your current result is different from your expected one. As long as `val` is not a falsy value the `WHERE :val` while be always _true_, so you will always get all entries  of `day_schedule`

Comment: Thanks Indrasinh and t oooooops yep missing the column. Corrected that but still get:"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in... on line 23".

Comment: (too slow to edit - sorry pushed "Enter" by mistake. Thanks Indrasinh and oooooops yep missing the column. Corrected that but still get:`"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in... on line 23"`. I took the second query into a separate file and ran it without the place holder still not working. Switched out the prepare bind execute for `$result = $pdo->query($sql)' worked fine. Thanks for your help. If you can see what is wrong I would be really grateful (thought it was the foreach but it is the prepare etc). Calling it a night for now. Will check back in the morning

Comment: you cannot bind column/table names in a prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

Change it:

```
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
```

to:

```
$result = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll();
```

In result2:

```
$result2=$s->execute();
```

to:

```
$s->execute();
$result2=$s->fetchAll(); //or ->fetch() if You want get one row
$s->closeCursor();
```

Comment: @trzyM- (complicated name!). Thanks for that but I am trying to use prepared statements. I am still horribly confused by PDO and PHP arrays in general but getting there. If I simply replace `$result2=$s->execute();` by  `$s->execute(); $result2=$s;` works exactly as I want. The first statement fails because of precedence I tried () and {} but could not force the issue but splitting it on to two lines gives me 100% of what I needed. Thanks for thoughts. Saved for after I get this alpha cobbled together :-)

Comment: No problem, good luck. In this statement You dont have `prepare` `$sql ="SELECT id FROM transmission WHERE person_id = 1` Simple query is ok. In both, You forgot fetch result. Thumb up if u like!

Answer (score 0):

If I simply replace 
    `$result2=$s->execute();`
 by 
    `$s->execute();` and
    `$result2=$s;` 
works exactly as I want. See comment on @trzyM-'s answer for more. 
Thanks all.